# Color gradient in d3 tree map based of another value

Tags: d3.js, observable

I am trying to see if a treemap chart can be done using d3 where the size of the box is based on value a and the color for that box is based on value b. I see this example https://observablehq.com/@d3/treemap

But any examples of using two values would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You need to map your data `domain` to your color `range` in your `scaleOrdinal` config.  In the example above a 10 color categorized color scheme instead

Comment: @varontron how do I do in this example https://observablehq.com/@senthilthyagarajan/treemap

Comment: Something like this: `var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["data1", "data2", "data3"])
        .range(["#fb5454", "#f1fb54", "#54befb"]);`  where the arguments to `domain` and `range` are arrays of equal length.  You can pre-calculate arrays from data and pass them to the functions.

Comment: @varontron I did do that but the colors are still the same observablehq.com/@senthilthyagarajan/treemap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your scale's domain with your leaves' parent nodes:

```
color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(treemap(data).leaves().map(d => {return d.parent.data.name}))
.range(d3.schemeCategory10)
```

And fill your leaf nodes with the corresponding gradient of color from the range, indexed by data value, applied to the opacity attribute:

```
.attr("fill", d => { return color(d.parent.data.name) })
.attr("fill-opacity", d => { 
        let min = d3.min(root.leaves().map(leaf => leaf.data.value))
        let max = d3.max(root.leaves().map(leaf => leaf.data.value))
        return (d.data.value-min)/(max-min)  
      })
```

You get only 3 colors, because you have only 3 parent nodes, but the colors correspond to the those in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic#schemeCategory10)

See [example](https://observablehq.com/@varontron/treemap)

**EDITED** per comment

Comment: I understand that I will get three colors . But what I want to do is for first parent if it’s blue change the color gradients for those children element based on the numbers I have in count for each of them

Comment: I have a similar issue but now with sizes. I have a new question for that here . Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100877/size-of-rectangle-in-d3js-based-on-sum-of-values-but-not-count-of-items